# Python Check if item in list is free

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I've got an `array`, that contains 9 char variables. I print them in a row of 3 using `for` loop. I would like to check if 2 of 3 variables in a row are the same and create function that will change the third one to match the others.
I would like to do it both vertically and horizontally.
 Do i have to change my **array** into **2D array**?
 It would made me to change nearly half of the code.
Is there a chance that i wouldn't have to write the `if` statements manually like this:

```
if array[0] == array[1]:
    change the_third_var
elif array[1] == array[2]:
    change the_first_var
elif array[0] == array[2]:
    change the_sec_var
```

but it will check it automatically using `for` or any other loop?
Will the solution help me to simplify the code below (optional)?

```
def check_winner(pl_array, player_choice, computer_choice):
    vertical = [2, 5, 8]
    diagonal = [6, 7, 8]
    # checking vertical lines
    for each in vertical:
        if pl_array[each - 2] == pl_array[each - 1] == pl_array[each]:
            if pl_array[each] == player_choice or pl_array[each] == computer_choice:
                return True
    # checking diagonal lines
    for every in diagonal:
        if pl_array[every - 6] == pl_array[every - 3] == pl_array[every]:
            if pl_array[every] == player_choice or pl_array[every] == computer_choice:
                return True
    # across
    if pl_array[8] == pl_array[4] == pl_array[0]:
        if pl_array[8] == player_choice or pl_array[8] == computer_choice:
            return True
    elif pl_array[6] == pl_array[4] == pl_array[2]:
        if pl_array[6] == player_choice or pl_array[2] == computer_choice:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample input and output?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to score tic-tac-toe. [Here is one implementation](https://inventwithpython.com/chapter10.html) that I found when searching Google for "Python tic tac toe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's a little verbose I rather have the if/elif logic you posted than any other option. You can wrap it in a function and simply call it whenever you need which will reduce the amount of code.

That said, you can also do the following ugly thing:

```
for i in range(-1, 2):
    if arr[i-1] == arr[i]:
        arr[i+1] = arr[i]
```